# Entity Framework : setting value converter for type generically, including TPH types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

**Context**

I have this extension method which sets a `ValueConverter` to be used on all properties of a specific type in my entities:

```cs
public static ModelBuilder UseValueConverterForType(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, Type type, ValueConverter converter)
{
    var entityTypes = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().ToList();

    foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
    {
        var properties = entityType.ClrType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == type);

        foreach (var property in properties)
            modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.Name).Property(property.Name)
                .HasConversion(converter);

    return modelBuilder;
}
```

And it works great for the entities which are in a `DbSet` in my `DbContext`.

**Problem**: I now also have entities that are included using the table-per-hierarchy configuration:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ModLogEntry>()
    .HasDiscriminator<string>("discriminator")
    .HasValue<ActionModLogEntry>("action_entry")
    .HasValue<RevertedActionModLogEntry>("reverted_action_entry")
    .HasValue<RevertModLogEntry>("revert_entry")
    .HasValue<SupportBanModLogEntry>("support_ban_entry")
    .HasValue<SupportUnbanModLogEntry>("support_unban_entry");
```

and these types are not returned from `modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()` so the existing extension method does not work on them.

**Attempted Solution**

I tried adding the following code in my extension method to apply the converter to properties of classes in the assembly which inherit from each entity in the `DbSet`:

```cs
// within the foreach entityType in entityTypes

var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(entityType.ClrType);
var childTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => entityType.ClrType.IsAssignableFrom(x));

foreach (var childType in childTypes)
{
    var childProperties = childType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == type);
    foreach (var property in childProperties)
        modelBuilder.Entity(childType.Name).Property(property.Name)
            .HasConversion(converter);
}
```

but I get an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'ModeratorId' cannot be added to the type 'ActionModLogEntry' because no property type was specified and there is no corresponding CLR property or field. To add a shadow state property, the property type must be specified.

If I specify the type of the child property, I get another exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'ActionModLogEntry' is in shadow state. A valid model requires all entity types to have corresponding CLR type.

How can I modify my extension method to also apply the value converter to these entities?

Comment: These should be returned by `GetEntityTypes()`. Just make sure to call your extension method **after** all other fluent configuration code. In other words, at the end of the `OnModelCreating`, when all entities are discovered.

Comment: @IvanStoev Oh, of course, changing the order in OnModelCreating fixed it. Thank you